# bash -c has different argument semantics ($1 becomes $0!)

Tags: bash

```
$ bash -c 'echo "0 is $0 1 is $1"' abc def
0 is abc 1 is def

$ echo 'echo "0 is $0 1 is $1"' > bashtest

$ bash bashtest abc def
0 is bashtest 1 is abc
```

The second run is equivalent to if I turned bash test into a shellscript with the shebang and then ran it directly...

Basically I'm wondering why abc isn't always `$1`. It becomes `$0` when run with `bash -c`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also didn't know this. But the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) mentions it:

> **-c string:** If the -c option is present,  then  commands  are  read  from
>                    string.   If  there  are arguments after the string, they are
>                    assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

The `ARGUMENTS` section has an even more detailed explanation:

> ARGUMENTS
>
> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the
>   -s  option  has  been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the
>   name of a file containing shell commands.  If bash is invoked  in  this
>   fashion,  $0 is set to the name of the file, and the positional parame‐
>   ters are set to the remaining arguments.  Bash reads and executes  com‐
>   mands  from this file, then exits.  Bash's exit status is the exit sta‐
>   tus of the last command executed in the script.   If  no  commands  are
>   executed,  the  exit status is 0.  An attempt is first made to open the
>   file in the current directory, and, if no file is found, then the shell
>   searches the directories in PATH for the script.

Comment: It's reasonable, I guess. They sure don't have a good item to set to `$0`. I should have just looked up the manpage; shame on me.

Comment: @janos Really nice article. :) I would like to spent a comment. The only account I have is `google+` so far. Can't you allow anonymous comments? Note will be AFK for a while but return back here later....

Comment: Hey you guys are awesome, thanks for helping to keep SO such a nice place!!